# Code to distinguish non-integers, negative numbers, zeros not behaving correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x

im trying to code a script that calculates how many minutes there are in x days and prints out a anwser, if the user input is a negative number, a string or a 0 it should print a error messege.
Here is how far i have come

```
# global var

user_input = input('Click here and type how many days you want to know the minutes of\nthen press enter...\n')


# def for calculating minutes in x days

def calc_minutes(user_input):

    if user_input.isdigit() > 0:
        user_input_int = int(user_input)
        minutes_a_day = 1440
        calc_anwser = minutes_a_day * user_input_int
        return f'there are {calc_anwser} minutes in {user_input} days'

    else:

        if user_input == int():
            return 'ERROR: type something else then a string'

        if user_input == 0:
            return 'type a number above 0'

        if user_input < 0:
            return ' type a positive number'

print(calc_minutes(user_input))
```

i cant figure it out, if i type a positive number it works, it calculates how many minutes there are in the days u typed and prints it out.

but if you type 0 as input it still runs the calculation instead of giving the error messege.

and if you type a string or negative number it says the code isnt right and displays the red error crash messege(not the error messege i typed to be displayed)

could anyone explain why it cant use the code ive written for the negative numbers, strings and 0?

Comment: Think of Stack Overflow like a big FAQ, not like a discussion forum. Your title should describe the technical problem your question is about in such a way that someone else with the same problem can find it and learn from its answers. So don't talk about yourself; instead, talk about _the specific technical problem_.

Comment: `isdigit()` is true when the input is `0`, so it performs the calculation.

Comment: `isdigit()` doesn't return the numeric value of the input. So checking `> 0` doesn't tell you if the number is positive.

Comment: `user_input.isdigit()` evaluates to `True`, and in python `True > 0` evaluates to `True` also, so you want to compare the actual digit instead of comparing 'whether it is a digit with' with zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`user_input.isdigit()` just tells you if the input only contains digits. It returns a boolean, not the value of the number. So you can't compare it to tell if the number is more than `0`.

What's actually happening is that the boolean value `True` or `False` is converted to a number: `True == 1` and `False == 0`. That's being compared with 0.

The best way to do this is to call `int()` to try to convert the input to an integer, and use `try/except` to detect the error if it can't be converted. If it converts successfully, check there to see if it's positive.

```
def calc_minutes(user_input):
    try:
        user_input_int = int(user_input)
        if user_input_int <= 0:
            return 'ERROR: type a positive number'
        minutes_a_day = 1440
        calc_anwser = minutes_a_day * user_input_int
        return f'there are {calc_anwser} minutes in {user_input} days'
    except ValueError:
        return 'ERROR: type an integer'
```

Comment: `except`, not `catch` :)

Answer (score 1):

In the first if operator you don't check whether the number is positive, but whether the string you got is a number.

Possible solution:
First, convert the input string to integer type

```
user_input = int(input('...'))
```

Then, check if it's non-negative:

```
if user_input > 0:
```

Comment: This will give an error if input is non-numeric

Comment: Ofc, I assumed the input is correct. Adding a try - except statement is not a bad idea.